# TypeOrmModule Unable to connect to the database

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs, nest

I have this problem in my nest app.
my system is ubuntu and I use docker

[Nest] 26388  - 07/14/2023, 9:32:03 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
at Protocol.end (/home/IdeaProjects/f/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
at Socket. (/home/IdeaProjects/f/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
at Socket. (/home/IdeaProjects/f/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
at Socket.emit (node:events:523:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1367:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
--------------------

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:

mysql:
image: mysql:8.0.23
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
restart: always
environment:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
ports:
 - "3306:3307"

postgres:
image: postgres:13.1
restart: always
environment:
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
ports:
 - "5432:5432"
adminer:
image: adminer
restart: always
ports:
 - "8080:8080"
```

and in app.module.ts:

```
    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { AppController } from './app.controller';
    import { AppService } from './app.service';
    import { EventsController } from "@events/events.controller";
    import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
    
    @Module({
      imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type: 'mysql',
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3306,
        username: 'root',
        password: 'example',
        database: 'nest-events',
      })],
      controllers: [AppController, EventsController],
      providers: [AppService],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I am not great with Docker, but since I don't see a webserver component in your container, you may want to make sure you are connecting to the database container properly. It wouldn't be on localhost, it would be elsewhere. Here is a reference page that may help: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ 

This may not be your issue, but it is my best guess with just the composer file.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL docker expose the 3306 port by default (see [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/1bfa4724fe112b4246672ed2b3c42142f17d5636/8.0/Dockerfile.oracle))

Your port section for the mysql service should be

```
ports:
  - "3307:3306"
```

Edit:

You were trying to connect to the 3307 port on TypeORM.
So you needed to open the 3307 port externaly to communicate with the 3306 port exposed by MySQL.

If you want to use the 3306 in TypeOrm just use

```
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
```

The format for the `ports` argument is described [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) and it is HOST:CONTAINER

MySQL expose the 3306 by default so the CONTAINER port should be 3306

On the HOST part you cant put 3306 to be consistent or put whatever you want and it is this port that you need to use in TypeORM

Comment: I set  this:
 ports:
      - "3306:3307"
but i have error